# How to PIVOT / UNPIVOT certain columns in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, pivot, powerquery

I'm working with a data set which is structured in this manner ->

[image]

---

I want to perform a PIVOT operation on the last 2 columns (prod & feedback) so as to achieve this result ->

[image]

---

Few things to know ->

- There are a MAX of 6 prods (p1 to p6)
- There is a possibility that some prods may not have feedback.
- Eg: **id-1** has provided feedback for all prods BUT **id-3** had provided feedback for only 3 prods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In Power Query, select prod column and then pivot from the ribbon.
Use the following options.
[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTIw1AciIwMjIyCnIBNIRKYWK8XqYJMFEX75OCSNwZJ5qTikTYCEU35JBg5pUyDhmFOeWInLbjMkl4EEDIzQXYZb1hjZbkxpE/zSIKf5pZalFoHlQWYZGKOHGTRUMCVNkEMFUxrZ27EA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [id = _t, date = _t, prod = _t, feedback = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"id", Int64.Type}, {"date", type date}, {"prod", type text}, {"feedback", type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[prod]), "prod", "feedback")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```